# Error loading paramSweep_v3 in DoubletFinder in R

Tags: r, genome, seurat, rna-seq

I am trying to run DoubletFinder on a seurat object resulting from the integration of various data.

The integrated seurat object have been fully processed:

1. Normalization and FindVariableFeature pre-integration
2. ScaleData, RunPCA, FindNeighbors, FindClusters, RunUMAP on the integrated object.

However when I run, paramSweep_v3() function of DoubletFinder gives me an error even though `DoubletFinder` is successfully installed and loaded [`library(DoubletFinder)`]:

```
sweep.res.list_pbmc <- paramSweep_v3(data.seurat.filtered, PCs = 1:20, sct = FALSE)

Error in paramSweep_v3(data.seurat.filtered, PCs = 1:20, sct = FALSE) : 
  could not find function "paramSweep_v3"
```

How do I get DoubletFinder `paramSweep_v3` function to work?

Comment: Which version do you have? From [DoubletFinder Github](https://github.com/chris-mcginnis-ucsf/DoubletFinder): 'Updates (11/21/2023) Made compatible with Seurat v5 and removed '_v3' flag from relevant function names'.

Comment: Thank you that works, I guess with older versions on `DoubletFinder` it is just `paramSweep`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In older versions of DoubletFinder, `paramSweep` works for me as shown below;

```
sweep.res.list_pbmc <- paramSweep(data.seurat.filtered, PCs = 1:20, sct = FALSE)
```

Nevertheless, you can always download any specific function from the [repository](https://github.com/chris-mcginnis-ucsf/DoubletFinder/tree/master/R) and include it in the existing package.